# How to Split Text By Character?

Tags: java

> How could I Split String by character, 
>   I have String Like This.

String="Hello World";

> How to have output like This,When I Split This String and use New Line"\n" and "for loop":

```
Output:

H
e
l
l
o

W
o
r
l
d
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the string character by character and print it.

An example of you want could be the following in Java (using `charAt`):

```
for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); ++i) {
    System.out.println(string.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: what if i only try to output like this  the "Hel" was gone:


l
o

W
o
r
l
d

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8+, you can get an `IntStream` with [`CharSequence.chars()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--) and use that to print each `char` on a new line like

```
String str = "Hello World";
str.chars().forEachOrdered(ch -> System.out.println((char) ch));
```

**or** `split` on `""` and then `Stream` and `print` like

```
Stream.of(str.split("")).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuilder.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
   sb.append(string.charAt(i));
   if (i < string.length() - 1) {
      sb.append("\n");
   }
}

String result = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String testStr = "Hello World";
```

If you have to use [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) this will give an array of all the individual characters as strings.

```
String[] testStrArr = testStr.split("(?!^)");
```

And iterate over it using something like this:

```
for(String s : testStrArr)
      System.out.print(s + "\n");
```

Otherwise you can use [toCharArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) to get array of chars:

```
for(char c : testStr.toCharArray()) {
  System.out.print(c + "\n");
}
```